# Java Script Count Down Timer resets whenever page refreshes

Tags: javascript, php

I have PHP page, where I added a countdown for 30 min. and as it ticks when I refresh the page or perform a query of 'insert' and redirect back to that page, the timer gets reset.

I want the timer to be constant and continue count without any interruptions when the page gets refreshed.

My code goes as:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 30,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer">
  <div>Section</div>
  <div class="time">
    <strong>Time left: <span id="time">30:00</span></strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any Help Is Appreciated..

Comment: use ajax to display timer from database

Answer (score 1):

Use html5 local storage to update the timer value and when page load occurs read the timer value from local storage. I guess no other way.

Comment: @Utkanos Thankyou for support. Next time I will make sure it.

Comment: There are other ways though, such as using ajax and a backend to store the value.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your PHP page loads, the javascript is loaded with it. So

```
window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 30,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

is called and the timer starts at 5 minutes.

One solution would be to do an Ajax request in `window.onload` and get the remaining time.

Another solution would be to set the `fiveMinutes` variable (obviously it should be renamed more appropriately) via PHP, if the javascript code is inside your PHP file, like

```
<script>
...
var timeLeft = <?php echo $timeLeft ?>;
...
</script>
```

The first solution is the standard way to go and the second one is the easy way to go.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you could use local storage (if the your target clients support this feature [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs))

```
<script>
        function startTimer(duration, display) {
            var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

          setInterval(function () {
                minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
                seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
                timer = --timer;
                if (timer >= 0) {
                    localStorage.setItem('time', timer);
                    //timer = duration;
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            var countDown = 60 * 30;
            var oldVal = localStorage.getItem('time');
            if (oldVal && oldVal > 0) {
                countDown = oldVal;
            }
            var display = document.querySelector('#time');
            startTimer(countDown, display);
        };
</script>
```

edit: of course one must not forget to check whether the stored value is below zero.

Comment: what browser are you testing this on? and what version? maybe localstorage is not supported by it? I tried the code in multiple browsers and it works :/

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, you could store the current time with [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).
To do so you would save both `minutes` and `seconds` in each interval tick:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        localStorage.setItem("minutes", minutes); // <--
        localStorage.setItem("seconds", seconds); // <--
```

And in the load function you'd read from them and set the starting value appropriately. It's important to note that values are always stored as strings, and as such, it would be necessary to parse them back to numbers before passing them through:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var timeLeft = 60 * 30,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');

    var minutes = localStorage.getItem("minutes"); //read minutes
    var seconds = localStorage.getItem("seconds"); //read seconds

    if (minutes && seconds){
        timeLeft = Number(minutes) * 60 + Number(seconds); //set time with val from storage
    }

    startTimer(timeLeft, display);
};
```

I changed the name of your `fiveMinutes` to `timeLeft` to better reflect what it holds, and parsed both values to numbers with [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

It's also important to mention that while this does keep the value after refreshes, it doesn't "count" the time while the page was closed. So keep that in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of refreshing the whole page try to use Ajax for communication and modify your html page using javascript.

Comment: It's a comment merely suggesting an approach. It doesn't really provide the OP with any sort of answer - there's no code, for example. Other answers in this question: one suffers similarly, and has been downvoted accordingly. The other answer has code in it and is more than just a comment.

Comment: This would solve the problem for redirects, but do nothing to help with the timer resetting if the page is reloaded by the client, m4gic. And @utkanos, there's nothing here that would be more useful as a comment.

Comment: Hm. I may made a mistake when I supposed that the page refresh is something that can be avoided/replaced by using a bit more current technology. I am not sure that it is unavoidable, it seems I should have ask it before try to suggest some solution. Next time I will do that.